# Can a function have multiple domains?

Tags: functions

Suppose $f:A\to Z$. In addition to this mapping, can I *simultaneously* define $f$ separately such that $f:B\to W$ where $A\cap B=\emptyset$ ? This polymorphism of function domains makes sense to me, but would this be accepted mathematically? So when I come to use $f$ later on, the function used depends entirely on the domain to which the argument belongs.

Comment: Mathematically those would be different, unrelated functions. But maybe you are asking about [Piecewise functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Comment: Being concrete: let $f: \{1, 2\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the canonical inclusion. Can you give me an example of another definition of $f$ with a different domain?

Comment: @dxiv But what about polynomials of matrices, are those unrelated to polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @Hetebrij Technically, yes. Functions with differrent domains are unrelated, unless a separate argument is made to relate them somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function however you want, as long as *for every input in the domain there is exactly one output*.  Depending on your audience and the situation, it might be confusing to re-use the function name $f$ in this way.  Say $g: A \rightarrow Z$ and $h: B \rightarrow W$.  Then you can define $f: A \cup B \rightarrow Z \cup W$ by 
 $$f(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill g(x)    \hfill & \text{ if $x \in A$} \\
      \hfill h(x)    \hfill & \text{ if $x \in B$.} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Alternately, a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is defined to be a set of ordered pairs $f \subseteq X \times Y$ with the property that for each $x \in X$ there is a unique $y \in Y$ so $(x,y) \in f$.  So viewed as sets, if there are functions $g: A \rightarrow Z$ and $h: B \rightarrow W$ then $g \cup h$ is a perfectly well-defined function from $A \cup B$ to $Z \cup W$ as long as $A \cap B = \emptyset$, or else $g(x) = h(x)$ for all $x \in A \cap B$.

I would not say, however, that the $f$ has 'multiple domains'. It just has one domain, which happens to be the union $A \cup B$.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. In my exposition I am constructing a function $f$ whose related but different and disjoint domains I introduce gradually, so I like the idea that I can glue the functions $f_i$ together at the end to form one function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the construct you want is that of [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union), which connects a group of sets in a non-overlapping way.

If you have a function $f_1: A \to Z$ and a function $f_2: B \to W$, then they naturally induce a function $f: A \coprod B \to Z \coprod W$, where the $\coprod$ symbol denotes disjoint union of sets. Thus you have "glued" $f_1$ and $f_2$ to form a new function in the way you wanted.

This seems to capture your idea of allowing a function to have "multiple domains" (and codomains), though it technically is not the case: by definition a function can have only one domain and one codomain.